# Hashmap using lists as a buffer

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to create a hashmap that can store multiple values for one key, I know multimaps could do this but I also need to keep those value lists to a specific length. I need a each key to store a list of n values with those being the latest n values, i.e if i reached length n and I add another value the first one added will drop off the value list and the target length is maintained.

I started off the below code and want to change it so i can store/add to a list for a specific key.

```
       public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
           final int maxSize = 4;
           final LinkedHashMap<String, String> cache = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {
           @Override
           protected boolean removeEldestEntry(final Map.Entry eldest) {
               return size() > maxSize;
           }
       };
```

```
        cache.put("A", "A");
        System.out.println(cache);
        cache.put("B", "A");
        System.out.println(cache);
        cache.put("C", "A");
        System.out.println(cache);
        cache.put("D", "A");
        System.out.println(cache);
        cache.put("E", "A");
        System.out.println(cache);
        cache.put("F", "A");
        System.out.println(cache);
        cache.put("G", "A");
    }
```

```
Output:

    {A=A}
    {A=A, B=A}
    {A=A, B=A, C=A}
    {A=A, B=A, C=A, D=A}
    {B=A, C=A, D=A, E=A}
    {C=A, D=A, E=A, F=A}


I tried changing it to sth like this but can't get it working (python guy here who is getting started with java)
```

```
public LinkedHashMap filteroutliers(final String arg, final long arg2) throws Exception{
    final int bufferSize = 5;
    final LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Double>> bufferList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Double>>(){
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(final Map.Entry eldest){
            return size() < bufferSize;
        }
    };
    return bufferList;
}
```

Comment: What's about `HashMap<String, MyRingBuffer<MyDataType>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the HashMap and have your custom map something like this, here I maintained a `queue` to store the keys so when the limit reaches you can remove the earliest key-value pair (FIFO)

```
class CacheMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int MAX_SIZE;
    private Queue<K> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    public CacheMap(int capacity) {
        super();
        MAX_SIZE = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (super.size() < MAX_SIZE) {
            queue.add(key);
        } else {
            super.remove(queue.poll());
        }
        super.put(key, value);
        return value;
    }
  }
}
```